# ggplot2 texashousing data smoothing short term noises

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, time-series

I am working on Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 elegant graphics for data analysis chapter 11 exercises 11.3.1:

Here Wickham tried to remove the monthly trending in the data - txhousing in tidyverse:

```
deseas <- function(x, month) {
resid(lm(x ~ factor(month), na.action = na.exclude))
}

txhousing <- txhousing %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(rel_sales = deseas(log(sales), month))

ggplot(txhousing, aes(date, rel_sales)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = city), alpha = 1/5) + 
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red")
```

[image]

But the question is: The final plot shows a lot of short-term noise in the overall trend. How could you smooth this further to focus on long-term changes?
Since I am not quite familiar with time series, thus do not know how to smooth the short term variations...is there anyone who could kindly help me with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `geom_smooth` to add a trend line. `loess` is one of the smoothing methods.

```
ggplot(txhousing, aes(date, rel_sales)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = city), alpha = 1/5) + 
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh shoot...now I understood..feeling dumb right now but thanks a lot! I was totally off the track and thought in the wrong way..